# How can you tell which hash function was used to generate a hash value?

Tags: hash

Let's say I have a hash value that's 40 alphanumeric characters long. How can I find out which hash function was used to get that hash value?

Comment: If you know what was hashed, just recompute the hash and check.

Comment: With 40 characters, which I presume are hexadecimals, you are probably limited to 160 bit hash functions such as SHA-1 and RIPEMD-160, although partial hash values could - in principle - also be used. Sometimes a keyed hash value is also named a hash value; in that case you obviously need to know the key to validate the hash function & construct (e.g. HMAC).

Comment: Googling the hash value can lead to surprising results, and there are also rainbow tables present on the internet, in case you don't know the precise input. If the input is unknown to you and is sufficiently complex then the chance of finding the hash and therefore hash function is minimal. If you *do* find the hash value though you're certain that you've found the algorithm as well; duplicates (collisions) should not even happen for different hash functions (unless they are sufficiently broken).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes How can I know how many bits a hash value is? Is it 1 bit per character?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
Modern hash functions are designed to be indistinguishable from random data under any reasonable computational cost. If you could tell which of two hash functions created a certain output from unknown input it would suggest at least on of them is distinguishable from random and thus has some weakness in it.

Comment: You could try compute likely preimages with common hash functions, and see if you happen to get a match; but that's your only option...

Comment: That us why my answe explicitly added unknown input.  If you know the input or enough to narrow it down it'a a different story.